# Why is this limit infinity and not undefined?

Tags: calculus

[screenshot of question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pymAE.png)

I'm confused as to why the limit for the last question (third box) is infinity rather than undefined since when you try determining the limit you end up with 0 as the denominator. I was given the answers and the correct one for that question was said to be infinity.

Comment: The limit of a function at a point $a$ is actually only depends on the behavior of the function near $a$, and not at $a$ itself. So the value of the denominator at $a$ actually doesn't matter.

Comment: It is appalling that whoever wrote those answer condones writing$\,\text{“}{=\text{DNE''}}$ rather than just $\text{“DNE''}. \qquad$

Comment: When you say that a function has limit infinity at $a$, you actually mean that as you approach $a$, the function gets arbitrarily large, which is true in this case, since as the denominator gets closer and closer to zero, and the numerator remains constant, their ratio does become arbitrarily large

Comment: @MichaelHardy I think it's because the questions are from some online platform that uses a question generator. Anyway, if only the questions with correct answer DNE had no =, then you could automatically tell what the correct answer to those were.

Comment: @AlanAbraham : So the solution is to require the student to write $\text{“}{=}\text{''}$ in cases where that is appropriate and not where it's not, instead of putting $\text{“}{=}\text{''}$ in front of each blank space that is to be filled in.

Comment: @MichaelHardy That is a good solution, and I think you are right. The only adverse effect I could see with that is just formatting problems as some students might put spaces after the =, but that's an easy fix anyway. Maybe the designers were just lazy.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that the limit of the denominator is $0$ does not mean that the limit of the fraction as a whole does not exist. In fact ALL derivatives are limits as both the numerator and the denominator approach $0.$

You will notice in the instructions to this set of problems that $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ are possible answers. If the denominator approaches $0$ from above while the numerator approaches a positive number, then the fraction as a whole approaches $+\infty.$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac {f(1.5)}{g(1.5)}$ is not defined.  But but the $\lim_{x\to 1.5}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is not the same thing as $\frac {f(1.5)}{g(1.5)}$.

$\infty$ is not a number and $\lim_{x\to 1.5}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\infty$ is not a statement about the limit actually being any value-- it is a statement about the *behavior* of the function at values *near* but not equal to $1.5$.

Now admittedly, $\lim_{x \to a} h(x) = k$ where $k$ is a finite value does refer to a value and we informally refer to $\lim_{x\to a}h(x)$ as being the same as that value, but that not really the point.  The point is the *sentence* $\lim_{x \to a} h(x) = k$ refers to how $h(x)$ behaves at values near but not equal to $a$-- namely it is a sentence saying "when $x$ is close to $a$ but not equal to $a$ then $h(x)$ is close to $k$".

But that's not the only way a function can behave and that is not the only thing one can say about the behavior.  It could be, as it is with $\frac {f(x)}{g(x)}$ when $x$ is near $1.5$, that $h(x)$ is consistently unbounded and unlimited and as $x$ gets very near $a$ then $h(x)$ gets large and there is no upper bound to how large it is.

When that is the case the sentence we use to describe that is $\lim_{x\to a} h(x) = \infty$.

$\infty$ in this case is not actually any number at all.